# quartz-scheduler depend jobs

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm working on a project with Quartz and has been a problem with the dependencies with jobs.

we have a setup where A and B aren't dependent on eachother, though C is:

A and B can run at the same time, but C can only run when both A and B are complete.

Is there a way to set this kind of scenario up in Quartz, so that C will only trigger when A and B finish?

Answer (score 3):

Not directly AFAIK, but it should be not too hard to use a [TriggerListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/TriggerListeners) to implement such a functionality (a TriggerListener is run both a start and end of jobs, and you can set them up for individual triggers or trigger groups).

EDIT: there is even a specific [FAQ Topic](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-chain) about this problem:

> There currently is no "direct" or "free" way to chain triggers with
>   Quartz. However there are several ways you can accomplish it without
>   much effort. Below is an outline of a couple approaches:
>
> One way is to use a listener (i.e. a TriggerListener, JobListener or
>   SchedulerListener) that can notice the completion of a job/trigger and
>   then immediately schedule a new trigger to fire. This approach can get
>   a bit involved, since you'll have to inform the listener which job
>   follows which - and you may need to worry about persistence of this
>   information. See the listener
>   org.quartz.listeners.JobChainingJobListener which ships with Quartz -
>   as it already has some of this functionality.
>
> Another way is to build a Job that contains within its JobDataMap the
>   name of the next job to fire, and as the job completes (the last step
>   in its execute() method) have the job schedule the next job. Several
>   people are doing this and have had good luck. Most have made a base
>   (abstract) class that is a Job that knows how to get the job name and
>   group out of the JobDataMap using pre-defined keys (constants) and
>   contains code to schedule the identified job. This abstract Job's
>   implementation of execute() delegates to an abstract template method
>   such as "doWork()" (where the extending Job class's real work goes)
>   and then it contains the code for scheduling the follow-up job. Then
>   they simply make extensions of this class that included the work the
>   job should do. The usage of 'durable' jobs, or the overloaded
>   addJob(JobDetail, boolean, boolean) method (added in Quartz 2.2) helps
>   the application define all the jobs at once with their proper data,
>   without yet creating triggers to fire them (other than one trigger to
>   fire the first job in the chain).
>
> In the future, Quartz will provide a much cleaner way to do this, but
>   until then, you'll have to use one of the above approaches, or think
>   of yet another that works better for you.